# OOP/JavaScript - Delete object when deleting reference

Tags: javascript, oop

```
teachers = [{name: 'Mary'},{name: 'Karen'}]

students = [{name: 'Joe'},{name: 'Bill'}]

courses = [{
  name: 'math',
  teacher: teachers[0],
  students: [students[0]],
}]
```

When deleting an item in the `teachers` array, all items in the `courses` array with reference to that `teacher` object should be deleted, too. Is there a way or pattern for doing it without iterating through all items in `courses` array? (The real world application is much more complicated.)

Comment: Right now, you'd need to look up where the object is also referenced, then delete everything. Alternatively, do a clenup step and after deleting a teacher, delete any course that has `teacher` set to something that doesn't exist in `teachers`. It's basically the same logic but running the operations in a different order. Other than that, you can keep references of what's used where and then use those for deletion.

Comment: or you can delete by marking it deleted instead of removing from the array. For example `teachers[0].deleted = true` then respect that flag anywhere a `teacher` object is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can save `courses` in `new WeakMap()` it will solve your issue.

```
const coursesWeekMap = new WeakMap();
coursesWeekMap.set(teachers[0], {
  name: 'math',
  teacher: teachers[0],
  students: [students[0]],
});
```

Comment: Sounds cool! So the solution is that before deleting a `teacher`, `coursesWeakMap.delete(teacher[0])` should be called, right?

Comment: ```teachers.delete(teacher[0])``` that's all. Object with key teacher[0]  from coursesWeekMap will be deleted . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way or pattern for doing it without iterating through all items in courses array?

Not really, but a filter is an easy way to do this, you should do it before deletion, for the sake of neatness.

```
const deletedTeacher = {name: 'Mary'};
const changedCourses = courses.filter(c => c.teacher.name !== deletedTeacher.name);

// delete teacher from array whatever way you like, confirm that it has happened

courses = changedCourses
```